# PHP script get ip, check, insert and redirect

Tags: php

i dont know much about php but here my question:

How i do in php a script/page (index.php) that get user ip, check if it already exist in a txt file(iplist.txt). If exist send that user IP to (pay.html) if dont exist insert ip on the txt file(iplist.txt) and send to main.html page.

the files inside "(file)" is a exmaple to be easier to understand.

i already made the code to get ip and tryed inserting the ip on a file but failed lol.

```
        include 'getip.php';
        $user_ip = getUSerIP();
        echo "<h2> ".$user_ip." </h2>";
```

This code is abit of what i did on a file to test if i get the user id. If i execute it, it tells me the user IP on a page. i just could did this part.

Best regards.

Comment: get ip open the file using php file function loop over file and match not exist then insert and redirect :)

Comment: @RakeshSharma why will it take two (!) days? what are you planning to do here? :-P

Comment: If the file is small you can use file_get_contents() to read it and file_put_contents to write.

Comment: @RakeshSharma okay, fine ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are using this for but putting in into a txt file will decrease the performance by a lot as soon as their are many entrances in it. The best idea would be using a database which you can easily search in with a SELECT.

Comment: Honestly, the whole thing sounds sketchy... "redirect to pay.html (?!) if the IP is in a list"? What are you trying to do here?! Whatever it is, I'd bet you'd get thousands of false positives or other problems.

Comment: @Wesley de Keirsmaeker i think i go use a database as you said, seems much better. thanks ^-^

Comment: Keep in mind that most users will get a new IP every 24h, so filtering them based on that alone is extremely unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a user's IP address like this:

```
$ip = $SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
//if user redirected from Proxy server then 
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
{
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
{
  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
 }
```

After getting IP you can check it exists or not:

```
$content=file_get_contents('iplist.txt');
if(strpos($content,$ip) !== false)
{
   Header("Location:pay.html");
}
else
{
   $content .= $ip."|^^|";
   $byte = file_put_contents("iplist.txt",$content);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for allowing me to spoof my IP address by simply setting an HTTP header!